# How to backup up with CrashPlan to Google Drive?

Tags: backup, google-drive, crashplan

Can you use the free version of [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com/%27) to backup your hard drive, or most likely a subset thereof, to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/), assuming of course you have enough available space on Google Drive? Are there any "tricks" required for this?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  CrashPlan backs up your content to their own servers and other locations on your network.  I suppose you could tell it that your Google Drive directory should be used although I would worry about running out of space.  Considering your using the `unpaid` version of CrashPlan your options will be limited.

Answer (score 1):

When I tested this, I noticed that Google Drive would not synchronize just the bytes that changed in the archive files but the whole files. So if you have a 4 GB backup, this will get uploaded each time a backed up file changes. I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what, or if, Google drive limit the types of file you write to their folder. In theory, it should work. I have not tried it, but, under Destinations, select Folders, Click select, and go to your Google Drive folder. Create a new folder and start backing up to that folder. I cannot guarantee that it will work, and you might want to try it on a smaller bunch of files first, and do some tests of restoring files, etc, but, as I said, in theory, it should work...